# How to implement a custom sink in Append and Update mode in Apache Spark 2.3?

Tags: apache-spark

How to implement a custom sink in Append and Update mode in Apache Spark 2.3?

I understand that I need to implement the below interface however what is not clear to me is what to consider and how to handle different output modes when implementing a custom sink?

```
trait Sink {
  def addBatch(batchId: Long, data: DataFrame): Unit
}
```